# dynamic form requirements from model

Tags: django-forms

I'm trying to generate a dynamic registration form, based on on specific client needs. I've created a UserProfile model with most of the fields set as blank=True.

When the form gets generated, I pull the client specified fields from another db table and generate the registration form. All this works, except that all the fields allow blank values.  So far I have this

```
def RegProfileForm(include_list, *args, **kwargs):
    class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = hr.UserProfile
            fields = include_list

        def __init__(self):
            super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    return ProfileForm()
```

Then I call this form like this:

```
includes = ['gender','work_phone'] # dynamic fields
of = RegProfileForm(includes)
```

How do I dynamically remove the blank=True requirement from certain specified fields during runtime, or when I generate the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out I can just do something like this to override the default values from the model:

```
form = MyAuthForm(data)
form.fields['first_name'].required = True
form.fields['email'].required = False
```