# How to change models.Model and admin.ModelAdmin data on object initialization in Django?

Tags: django

```
<!-- language: lang-default -->
    class Seo(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField( max_length=500,  blank=True)
          description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
          keywords = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
          url = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
          static = models.BooleanField()

    class SeoInlines(generic.GenericStackedInline):
        model = Seo
        form = SeoForm
        extra = 1 
        max_num = 1
```

I need to make `Seo.url` not editable (`editable=False` or `SeoInlines.exclude = ('url', )` or `SeoInlines.readonly_fields = ('url',)`) when `seo.static = 1`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already said it:

```
url = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, editable=False)
```

Then what you can do is override your form definition if static = 1. I'm assuming the problem only comes in for record updates not initial saves. You can check out how to do this dynamically [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740837/dynamic-form-requirements-from-model)